# Applying WS-Security to raw SOAP payload

Tags: java, ws-security

Using a Java-based integration engine (Mirth, for the curious), I have a need to sign a SOAP payload that is passing through the engine. All I have is the raw unsigned SOAP XML and the ability to install extensions and call into Java APIs.

So far my google searches haven't revealed any APIs/frameworks that effectively allow me to effectively set WS-Security parameters and then pass it the raw payload to sign. Installing a 3rd party jar that supplies this capability isn't an issue if that's what is needed. I had a look at Apache-CXF and JAX-WS but from what I can tell they work with stubbed out Java classes, rather than raw payload.

Have I missed something obvious, or am I going to have to write a custom WS-Security implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WSS4J](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/) library supports signing any XML parsed with DOM or STAX API (SOAP message or not). You can find examples in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/wss4j) of the unit tests (folders ws-security-dom for DOM API, and ws-security-stax for StaX API).

For example, if you are using the DOM API, the code of [CertificateStoreTest#testSignatureDirectReference()](https://github.com/apache/wss4j/blob/trunk/ws-security-dom/src/test/java/org/apache/wss4j/dom/components/crypto/CertificateStoreTest.java#L78) shows how to sign a SOAPPart which is a SOAP payload parsed into a DOM Document.